# Multiline strings in Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, string, roslyn

I'm reading [Taking a tour of Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/04/03/taking-a-tour-of-roslyn.aspx), and it says:

> An example for VB which demonstrates a new feature would be:
>
> ```
> Sub Main()
>     Dim s As String = "This is a multiline
>         string literal."
> End Sub
> ```
>
> which was impossible using the old VB compiler.

Why was it impossible using the old VB compiler, and how did they manage to fix it in Roslyn?

Comment: Concat string with `VbCrlf` or `Environment.NewLine`, I think this can help you.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Thanks but that's totally not what I'm asking.

Comment: It isn't? That string contains a "literal" newline is all.

Comment: I'm not asking how to concatenate strings in VB .NET - read the question itself (the last sentence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old compiler just didn't allow it (because the language was line based), and when the Roslyn scanner and parser were implemented, we added support to continue scanning through newlines as part of string literals.